GWT JsInterop and TypeScript index signature
I´m traying to implement the js library Handsonetable and Hyperformula (leatests versions) with a application written in java with GWT.
I´m using JsInterop to integrate but there are parts that i don´t know how to map in java.
As example:
export interface ImplementedFunctions {
  [formulaId: string]: FunctionMetadata,
}

That is used to implement a custom function to hyperformula, the providen example is:
export class MyCustomPlugin extends FunctionPlugin {}


MyCustomPlugin.implementedFunctions = {
  DOUBLE_RANGE: {
    method: 'doubleRange',
    arraySizeMethod: 'doubleRangeResultArraySize',
    parameters: [{ argumentType: FunctionArgumentType.RANGE }],
  },
};

As you can see uses typescript index signature.
How can i implement that code in JsInterop.
Any help is appreciated.

Can you flesh out this question a bit more? What are you trying to from the GWT code, create a function that matches this interface, or try to consume such an interface from Java/GWT? What Java/GWT code do you have so far? And can you share the rest of the types you want to consume/produce from GWT?
